# Oracle STRUCT use OBJECT TYPE with CLOB attribute

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, struct, clob

I am trying to use STRUCT for the insertion of massive data in my table DATA_TABLE, but generate error (java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation) with data type field CLOB and I can't find a solution to my problem, my code:

My table

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_TABLE (DAT_ID     NUMBER,
                         DAT_CODE   VARCHAR2(10),
                         DAT_TEXT   CLOB);
```

Create type object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_OBJ_DATA AS OBJECT (DAT_ID    NUMBER,
                                              DAT_CODE  VARCHAR2(10),
                                              DAT_TEXT  CLOB);
```

create type table from type object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_TABLE_DATA AS TABLE OF SCHEMA.TY_OBJ_DATA;
```

My simplified java method

```
public static void bulkData(List<DataTable> listDataInfo) throws Exception {
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource");
  OracleConnection connection = ds.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
  try{       
      StructDescriptor typeTableObject = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("SCHEMA.TY_OBJ_DATA", conect);
      STRUCT[] structData = new STRUCT[DataTable.size()];
      int counter= 0;
      for (DataTable d : listDataInfo) {
           Clob clob = connection.createClob();
           STRUCT m = new STRUCT(typeTableObject, connection,
                      new Object[]{d.getDatId(),
                                   d.getDatCode,
                                   clob.setString(1, d.getDatText)});
                structData [counter++] = m;
           }
           ArrayDescriptor tyTable = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SCHEMA.TY_TABLE_DATA", connection);
           ARRAY array = new ARRAY(tyTable, connection, structData);
           String sqlQuery = "{ CALL PACKAGE_BULK.PL_BULK_DATA }";
           CallableStatement cst = conect.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
           cst.setArray(1, array );
           cst.execute();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new Exception(e);
     } finally {
       try {
            connection.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new Exception(e);
       }
     }
}
```

I omit the package code, because it is working correctly and is not my main problem. i Use ojdbc6 version 11.2.0, java 8 and Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit.

Is it possible to use STRUCT with fields of type CLOB? I am doing something wrong? my DatText field when it is remapped is of the String type and that was the best conversion that I managed to do from String to a clob but I still have problems, any idea how I can solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but as I just came by:

I solved this issue by simply skipping the descriptors and using:

```
cst.setArray(i, ((OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray("TY_TABLE_DATA", shiftArrayOneUp(new Object[]{d.getDatId(),
                               d.getDatCode(),
                               d.getDatText()}));
```

shiftArrayOneUp is just adding one empty value at the beginning (oracle array starts at 1, not at 0)

```
private Object[] shiftArrayOneUp(Object[] values) {
  Object[] result = new Object[values.length + 1];
  System.arraycopy(values, 0, result, 1, values.length);
  return result;
}
```

---

As I had to adjust my code accordingly, I did not test what I was writing here.
Maybe some small adjustments need to be done

Comment: needs  some results as information to support your answer